# Maximum DC power available over specific distances from source

Tags: power, dc, low-power, loss

I'm working on a small LVDC project using 60 VDC to distribute power over varying distances to varying loads such as network equipment. I decided to work out the maths and see exactly how much power I can get (maximum) over specific distances.

For this specific case I am assuming AWG14 (\$2.5\rm\, mm^2\$) cable is being used.

The voltage drop over the cable will be:

$$V_{drop} = I_{wire} \cdot R_{wire}.$$

The voltage available at the load will be:

$$V_{load} = V_{supply} - V_{drop},$$

which is equivalent to:

$$V_{load} = V_{supply} - \left( I_{wire} \cdot R_{wire} \right).$$

Resistance of a wire is

$$R_{wire} = {2 \cdot L_{[\rm m]} R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m}. $$

Re-writing:

$$V_{load} = V_{supply} - I_{wire}
{2 \cdot L_{[\rm m]} \cdot R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m}.$$

Power will be given by voltage at the load times current in the wire. Voltage supplied in this case is 60 V so the resulting expression for power at the load can be written:

$$\begin{aligned}
P_{load}
&= \left( 60{\,\rm V} - I_{wire} 
{2 \cdot L_{[\rm m]} R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m}
\right) \cdot I_{wire} \\
&= 60{\,\rm V} \cdot I_{wire} - I_{wire}^2
{2 \cdot L_{[\rm m]} \cdot R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m}. \\
\end{aligned}$$

I am looking to maximize the power available at the load with respect to the current in the wire - so using partial differentiation:

$$\begin{aligned}
{\partial \over \partial I_{wire}} P_{load}
&= 60{\,\rm V} - 2\ I_{wire} \cdot 
{2 \cdot L_{[\rm m]} \cdot R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m} \\
&= 60{\,\rm V} - 4\ I_{wire} 
{L_{[\rm m]} \cdot R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} \over 1000\,\rm m}. \\
\end{aligned}$$

To maximize, set the derivative to zero and solve - yielding:

$$ I_{wire} = {15000 \over L_{[\rm m]} \cdot R_{wire[\rm\Omega/km]} }. $$

So for example, at 50 m with a wire resistance of 14 AWG as \$ 8.286 \, \Omega/{\rm km} \$:

$$ I_{wire} = {15000 \over 50 \cdot 8.286 } = 36.3 {\,\rm A}. $$

At this current, the maximum power is achieved. The voltage drop with this current can be calculated to be approx. 30 V, so the power delivered would be just over 1 kW at 1086 W.

Obviously 36.26 A is a lot of current especially for 14AWG so I would cap this at a much lower level or use 3 cables to divide the current by 3.

30 V at the end of the cable can then be stepped-up or down depending on device. So taking around 10-15 % losses in efficiency for the DC/DC converter - around 900 W can be transmitted at 60 VDC over 50 m.

I want to expand this to longer distances such as 200 m, 300 m and maybe further. Just want to check my thinking/maths is correct as it may be useful for someone else who may come across the same question.

Comment: Maximum power is simply given by the Max Power Transfer Theorem (which you derived from scratch!) - but this is usually the wrong question, because you don't usually want to waste 50% of the input power in the cable. However you are in a strong position to define the efficiency you can live with - and deduce the cable size (or no, of 14Ga cables) you need to achieve that.

Comment: Maximum Power Transfer Theorem only applies when the Series resistance (wire in your case) is fixed (known) and you want to adjust the load resistance for maximum power. If the load resistance is known, the load power is maximized when the series (wire) resistance is zero! An old trick question that my professor would use.

Comment: Do be aware that the resistance of copper wire changes with temperature, and that temperature limits of insulation are a thing. Your single 14AWG wire at 36A will be running at something silly like 110C (https://www.hilltop-products.co.uk/media/44A%2030-14%20AWG.pdf). As you say, you can run multiple in parallel; running multiple in parallel affects the resistance.

Comment: If you are already running a DC/DC converter at the far end, it's often (not always) better to step up the voltage instead, local regulations permitting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I'm working on a small LVDC project using 60VDC to distribute power
> over varying distances*

OK, 60 volts is the input voltage.

> *The voltage drop with this current can be calculated to be approx. 30V*

For maximum power transfer, the volt drop of the cable series resistance will always be 50% of the applied voltage hence it will be exactly 30 volts. Maximum power available at the load will be: -

$$\dfrac{V_{SUPPLY}^2}{4\cdot R_{CABLE}}$$

> *Just want to check my thinking/maths is correct*

Well, I think you went the long way round and proved the well-known [maximum power transfer theorem](https://byjus.com/physics/maximum-power-transfer-theorem/#:%7E:text=Maximum%20Power%20Transfer%20Theorem%20explains,as%20Thevenin%27s%20equivalent%20resistance.) so good work.

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps my search terms into google and other sites weren't along those lines so I missed this theorem. Anyways, good learning I guess... cheers!

Comment: Side question - if I wanted to test this using a 1km drum of cable would there be any issues? I understand that heat may be an issue so would need to keep current low. But surely the big coil of wire would act as a massive inductor of sorts? So would need to ensure the load can be safely disconnected?

Comment: The cable will have forward and return wires closely coupled thus, net-inductance might be of the order 250 nH per metre. 1 km might have an inductance of 250 uH but, there is the distributed capacitance of the cable which will keep back-emfs under control. You can always test the cable with no load except an oscilloscope; short out the cable momentarily and look at the back-emf on the scope @BrandonKellett

Comment: @BrandonKellett You can test it using an \$ 8 \Omega \$ resistor, or a drum of cable. At timescales of seconds, both will be roughly equal. If you'll be testing using wire, you can use full current for a couple seconds, then wait 10 minutes for cooling. But you *absolutely* have to unwind the wire and lay it flat on the ground, so that it can properly cool. Otherwise, you'll have a melted slag of plastic on the drum, with copper embedded in it :) I've seen this happen when a wire test went astray: I got distracted and left for lunch. It was a $5k lunch in spite of much lower currents :/

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica even with low currents with respect to the cable I should still unwind? Why would they heat up more than normal using typically acceptable current for a specific wire gauge. I'm not going to try push say 30A through a cable because I know that that would be pretty insane.. but what about 10A or so?

Answer (score 4):

As your math indicates, for a given resistance of cable maximum power is transferred when volt drop in the cable is equal to half the supply voltage.

However given your goal is to supply network equipment, which presumably will be supplied by switch-mode converters I would caution you that normal switch-mode converters do not mix well with high impedance power supplies.

Generally within it's operating range, a switch-mode converter with a load approximates a constant power load.

If you plot the characteristics of your supply and the characteristics of a constant power load you will normally find they intersect in two places. The higher-voltage of the two intersections represents the desired operating point. The lower voltage represents the voltage below which the load will try to draw more current than is available.

Real world systems don't jump instantly from "power off" to normal operation, every system has capaciance so when power is applied to a discharged system starts the voltage rises gradually. If you had a true constant power load the system would never be able to start.

Fortunately switch-mode converters are not constant power loads over the full range of possible input voltages. In practice they have a minimum voltage below which they do not operate normally. A buck converter cannot produce an output voltage higher than it's input voltage. A boost converter can, but nearly all boost converters will be designed with an under-voltage lockout.

To reliably supply a switch-mode converter you need to be able to not just deliver enough power to supply the load under good operating conditions, you have to be able to deliver enough power as soon as the voltage becomes sufficiently high. Worse since the converter likely has output capacitance to charge you may need to be able to supply more power during startup than during normal operation.

Unfortunately the precise figures for what voltage a converter will start up and how much current it will draw from the supply during the start-up phase are often not readily available, so it may be a case of suck it and see to find out how much resistance in the supply you can get away with before your converter fails to start.

Comment: Thanks for that Peter. Yes you are correct in that I will be using DC/DC converters at the far end to power my equipment. Either 12V,24V or 48V DC/DC converters to then directly power the equipment. Most of the devices datasheets do list the peak current draw they require - so if I design for this along with inefficiencies in the DC/DC conversion I should be ok? I don't expect any single load to be over say 200W